# Design specs for the attributes of this text class

Tags: java

I have created a class that formats text accorrding to specs my question is, are my attributes correct or are they not implemented correctly according to the specs? I am just confused on the alignment, style and size. I imported the java.awt for all of them. [spec for attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uUxR.png) [code with attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN7mw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Correct.

The spec says the alignment can be constants SwingConstants.LEFT, SwingConstants.CENTER or SwingConstants.RIGHT which are all of type int.
These constants can be looked up in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html).

Similarly the style can be Font.PLAIN, Font.BOLD, Font.ITALIC which are all of type int. Again check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html).